# delayed payouts stripe connect node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am creating an application in which a user can sign up, and a marketplace admin can send them offers, in which the user can accept these offers and pay for them. my platform acts as the middle man for the payments, all payments are done using stripe. I am using `stripe connect` to do so, where marketplace admins sign up to a stripe connect account via my platform, where they connect their bank details etc, to get paid out.

Here's my code for actually processing a payment to the connect account:

```
 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    mode: 'payment',
    line_items: [
      {
        price_data: {
            unit_amount: doc.milestones[0].price * 100,
            currency: 'cad',
            product_data: {
              name: 'Milestone ' + doc.milestones[0].milestone + ': ' + doc.milestones[0].milestone_name,
              description: doc.milestones[0].milestone_desc
            },
          },
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    payment_intent_data: {
      application_fee_amount: (doc.milestones[0].price * 100) * 0.05,
      transfer_data: {
        destination: doc.connect_account_id
      },
    },
    customer_email: doc.client,
    success_url: 'http://localhost:3001/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3001/cancel',
  });
  
  req.session.payment_session_id = session.id
  req.session.project_id = doc.project_id
  res.redirect(session.url)
```

what I am now looking to do is actually add a buffer / delay period to the payment being deposited into the marketplace admins account. Basically, I want to make sure the marketplace admins actually complete the order they've been asked to do, and don't want to transfer them before it is completed, as it would give them a reason not to do the job. Just wondering if this is possible / how to do it. I looked into the `delay_days` property, but it didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [doing the charge and transfer separately](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/separate-charges-and-transfers). You could only [execute the transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create) of funds to the connect account once the order has been fulfilled.